# Why is the Accept header prefixed with HTTP_?

Tags: http, header, http-headers

I've noticed that it's almost an universal convention to prefix Http headers with HTTP_ when accessing them from a web server.  Can anyone explain to me the circumstances about how this came about?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're talking about CGI scripts. The HTTP headers are passed as environment variables. As there may be other environment variables that have nothing to do with HTTP (eg: PATH), it makes sense to tack on a common prefix to reduce the chance of collisions.